# Panning Past And To Image Boundaires

Tags: matlab

What is the property that controls whether or not the interactive pan tool can pan beyond the boundary of the image? Also, how does one set the allowable limits of panning?

Once the axis limits have been set manually, Matlab seems to not allow panning beyond the image boundary. For instance, if you display the default image like so

```
figure;
image;
```

then you can pan beyond the boundaries of the image. However, if then you try setting the axis limits manually:

```
axis( [ 20 50 20 50 ] )
```

you'll see that panning is now limited to original boundaries of the image.

How do I control this behavior?

Comment: Interesting - there is `pan` but it doesn't seem to specifically allow the setting of pan limits.

Answer (score 1):

The only heuristic I've been able to find is if *any* plot bound is outside the content bounds, you can pan unrestrictedly.  But the moment the plot bounds are strictly within the content bounds, panning becomes restricted.  Try panning around after `axis([-1 30 -1 30])` in your example — the moment you pan the image such that it entirely fills the axes, you can no longer pan beyond the image boundary.

I've not found any way to override this behavior, but in some cases you can skirt around it by subtly extending the axis limits.  For example:

```
figure; image; axis('tight') % # Cannot pan in any direction
xlim(xlim() + eps(xlim()).*[-1 1]) % # Subtly extend xlimit beyond content bounds
% # Can now pan in all directions
```

In other cases, you can draw two tiny dots to extend the content bounds to where you want the limits to be:

```
figure; image; axis('tight')
line([-100 -100;nan nan;100 100],[-100 -100;nan nan;100 100], 'linewidth', eps(0), 'color', 'w')
% # Can now pan from -100 to 100 on both axes
```